# Get Glob Pattern From File List

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I'm trying to find an efficient way (or a ready-to-use package) for determining a glob that matches a given list of files.

For instance, I'd like to have a function, that is able to do something of this sort:

```js
getBestMatchingGlob(["./packages/my-server", "./packages/my-client"]); // returns `./packages/*` or maybe even `./packages/my-*` (given, that this is valid glob syntax)
```

Do you know of any module that has been written for such a use case?

I tried to use `common-path-prefix` and `common-path-suffix` in order to get matching parts of the paths and replace the non-matching parts with a star `*`.

However, I thought this is too much fiddling and that there probably is a pre-made solution somewhere already that I don't know of.